# Correct type annotation for a 2D transpose function in python

Tags: python, python-typing

In our code we do a lot of 2D transposes like `zip(*something)` where `something` is a list of tuples.

For example take:

```py
>>> a = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> result = tuple(*zip(*a))
>>> result # type checkers should reveal tuple[Iterable[str], Iterable[int]]
[('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3)]
```

In both MyPy ([Play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=525897b62bbde583e43d94084190a46f), [Issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5247)) and Pyright ([Play](https://pyright-play.net/?code=IYAgvCDaAUDkywDQgIwEplwEZJAJgxDgGNcBmNAXQCgAnAUwDd7gAbAfQBcBPAB3uicArr1YCAXgEte0AFTA0i6sqwAuEK0kBnTpGGj6kAGasA9sE7IdtZFm6d6WypXBQadJiw49%2B0KTNksJSA)) the type of `tuple(zip(*a))` reveals something like `tuple[Any]`. This causes the code to lose all type information, which I don't want.

Therefore, I want to create a special function `def transpose(iterable)` function that ensures the type checkers are aware of the resulting types.
A workaround to not lose type information.

How to do this?

Comment: The result of `tuple(zip(*a))` on a `list[tuple[str, int]]` isn't actually guaranteed to be a `tuple[Iterable[str], Iterable[int]]`. It could be an empty tuple, if the input list is empty.

Comment: Very good catch. I will add a value error in the [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77788482/3813064)

Answer (score 0):

A rather not very elegant but working solution is to rely on [overloads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload).

This will work as long as the number of elements in your tuple are low (5 in my example).

I tried to use [`TypeVarTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple) instead of [overloads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) but couldn't get it to work.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Iterable, Sized

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
T3 = TypeVar("T3")
T4 = TypeVar("T4")
T5 = TypeVar("T5")


@overload
def transpose(
    iterable: Iterable[tuple[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]], strict: bool = False
) -> tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], Iterable[T3], Iterable[T4], Iterable[T5]]:
    ...


@overload
def transpose(
    iterable: Iterable[tuple[T1, T2, T3, T4]], strict: bool = False
) -> tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], Iterable[T3], Iterable[T4]]:
    ...


@overload
def transpose(
    iterable: Iterable[tuple[T1, T2, T3]], strict: bool = False
) -> tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], Iterable[T3]]:
    ...


@overload
def transpose(
    iterable: Iterable[tuple[T1, T2]], strict: bool = False
) -> tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2]]:
    ...


def transpose(
    iterable: (
        Iterable[tuple[T1, T2]]
        | Iterable[tuple[T1, T2, T3]]
        | Iterable[tuple[T1, T2, T3, T4]]
        | Iterable[tuple[T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]]
    ),
    strict: bool = False,
) -> (
    tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2]]
    | tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], Iterable[T3]]
    | tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], Iterable[T3], Iterable[T4]]
    | tuple[Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2], Iterable[T3], Iterable[T4], Iterable[T5]]
):
    """
    Transpose the elements of given iterable, type safe

    WARNING: The result is a zip object and **NOT** a tuple so `transpose(…)[0]` won't work
    Use tuple unpacking `x, y = transpose(…)` instead
    We still keep it this way as converting it to a tuple would have performace costs.

    Only a typed shortcut for zip(*iterable)
    See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5247 for background
    """
    if isinstance(iterable, Sized) and len(iterable) == 0:
        # we want to be type safe, if iterable is empty we don't know how big the
        # resulting tuple would be, so we don't accept this
        raise ValueError("Empty iterable")
    return zip(*iterable, strict=strict)  # type: ignore
```

Comment: It seems super weird that you've added a warning comment stating that the returned value is not of the annotated type, especially when the question/answer deals pointedly with getting the annotated type correct.

Comment: I know it rather not perfect. But there is no other way to type it more correct at the moment. There is no way of telling the type checker: This function returns an Iterable (which can be used in tuple expansion) with the types `T1`, `T2`, … and use anything else than tuple. `Any` is the worst kind of type, because it allows everything. My solution at least keeps the types used inside the iterables intact.

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted. The WARNING comment is correct and, indeed, important (because `tuple` is Sized, unlike `zip`, so we're actually lying not entirely safely) - but this type is very close to type correctness. This is likely the best workaround until we have transformations on variadic generics. The only thing: please name it `_transpose` (internal) because of the hackery involved unless you really need it public for some reason.

Comment: In my case this function is part of our common libs. I think it is up to the users to name the their function and in the question I asked for a `transpose` function so I like to keep it consistent.